# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No Connection Could Be Made

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, xampp

I'm new to Laravel. When I migrated my table I got the following error.

> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it.

**Database info**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3036
DB_DATABASE=Monu
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=''
```

When I type `php artisan migrate` I get that error.

Comment: have you changed the default port of mysql?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

change port to `DB_PORT=3306` the
run the following commands

1.`php artisan config:clear`

2.`php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: Check this and let me know whether it was useful @Hasib Akon

Comment: this doesn't work! Also explain why you're advising for someone to use the artisan commands you posted. Dont just let people assume!

Comment: this doesn't work! Also explain why you're advising for someone to use the artisan commands you posted. Dont just let people assume!

Comment: @NMukama default port for database is 3306 but in this question was written incorrectly 3036
after that I suggested to clear cache to insure Laravel use new configuration
Configuration cache cleared!
Application cache cleared!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the 127.0.0.1 to localhost and let me know if that does it :D If thats not it try create a user other than root with full privileges over your laravel DB

Comment: No problem glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your `WAMP` Server (or `XAMP`) is working. And also check whether the MySQL server is running or not. This could happen if you do not run the apache server(or the server you use). After starting your local server, refresh the page